# Android Google Maps v2, MAP_TYPE_NONE and black squares

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I've been struggeling with Google Maps v2 and custom tiles. It works fine, but we get **black squares** in Google Maps very often, and they are very distruptive.

I can reproduce the problem very simply by doing this:

```
mapFragment = new MapFragment() {
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mapFragment.getMap().setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
    }
};

FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
trans.replace(R.id.map, mapFragment);
trans.commit();
```

I use this code and a standard activity with a framelayout. If I zoom far enough in the background on my Nexus4 it turns black. If I put tiles on top of that I will **see black flashes as I zoom in**.

I've seen a ton of workarounds on how to fix this, and none of them seem to work at all. It seems to only happen on certain zoom levels, but I (A) need those zoom levels, and (B) cannot seem to limit zooming (without building a custom pinch to zoom implementation anyways).

I've done some testing with custom tile providers. With `MAP_TYPE_NONE`, a tile provider which simply returns 1 blue pixel and my normal map tile provider I can visually see the map changing from black -> blue -> my map. Even though my custom blue tile provider returns immediately with a 1px blue tile.

Comment: note that in order to see this you need to set the view background to something other than black. We've been using the android theme holo light.

Comment: do you mean, you didn't get map image, just get grids right?

Comment: flashes black first, then I get the grid, then I get the map image.

Comment: could you please put links to the workarounds that you mention in your question so we can see which ones you've tried? thx

Answer (score 1):

This issue, as well as a trailing black rectangle when moving the Map view, was reported months ago and has just received a fix from Google.

This fix is unfortunately limited to compatible devices and because it's a fresh fix, may introduce new bugs on the "fixed" devices and keep the old ones (a bit different) on the other devices.

I don't see any need to copy here the conversation from Google's bug tracker since it's fully public:
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4659